# How to force the application to stop until an operation finish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have an application that require a lot of compilations .Therefore,I need the application to wait until the operation ends .To be more specific , I work on Tkinter and Canvas.So,when I want to move an item it takes some seconds to do so and the widget would not respond .
Thanks for advance .

Comment: Tkinter is single-threaded, so if you do a long calculation it's already going to stop and wait. I'm not sure what you're really wanting to do.

Comment: for exemple ,when you have a bad connexion and you want to access to a website then you have to wait and they show you an animation that turning around until the website opens .It's the same thing for me ,I want the user to be informed that he has to wait .